# Fancy notification when user clicks a link

Tags: jquery

Is there a good way to show a fancy notification to a user when they click a link. Then the link will show a fullspace popup menu that consist option for them. For example they can go delete something on or go back to?

Comment: I have no idea what this is saying. Make the text flip in 3D and `<blink>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure what the question's asking - heres my best shot at an answer.

have the link in an element (say a div) with a `position:relative;` then put the popup menu in another div WITHIN the div you just put the link in. Set this div with `position:absolute;display: none;bottom: 50px;` then in jquery do this:

```
$("a").click(
    function(){
        $("this").parent().find("div").show();
    });
```

is that what you want?